# Implementing Google Custom Search on wordlist

Tags: elasticsearch, google-custom-search

What would be the best way to use Google Custom search (or any alternative Google service) to search over a wordlist.
The wordlist in question is of around 4.5 million strings (which are word or combination of words). I am looking to give a word as input and find the most similar 10 strings as result. I know elastic search is one option but the result are not satisfactory (in terms of relevancy and not speed).

Comment: What level of customization do you have on your elasticsearch? The relevancy is only as good as your configuration.

Comment: My issue is I need phonetic search as well. And when I try to combine phonetic with the general search over elastic search, despite multiple iterations of varying permutation and combination, I am unable to settle for something that gives acceptable level of results.

Comment: Your question is vague. "Satisfactory" and "Acceptable" are relative words. You should probably update with some examples, quoting what you are expecting Vs what you are seeing.